# trying to remove margin-right of my "<ul>" element

Tags: html, css

Im have 3 columns with list items, and I dont understand why my first column (#col1) have a margin-right tha the other columns dont have.
I want that the margin-right is icual for all of my columns but Im not having sucesso doing this.
Do you see where might be the problem?

**My jsfiddle with the problem:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/r2Y6d/4/

my html:

```
<div id="body-content">
            <h1>Title</h1>

           <img src="image1.jpg" width="700px" height="360px" />
            <div id="info">
          <h1>Info</h1>
          <ul id="col1">
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone" title="phone"></i>Phone</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-print" title="Fax"></i>Phone</li>

          </ul>
          <ul id="col2">
            <li><i class="fa fa-home" title="adress"></i> Adress</li>

             <li ><i class="fa fa-map-marker" title="Map"></i><a  class="button" href="#showMap"><span>Show map</span></a></li>   
         </ul>
          <ul id="col3">
            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" title="phone"></i>Email</li>

            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" title="Email"></i>Email</li>       
          </ul>
         </div>
```

**My css:**

```
#info h1{color:red; font-size:23px; margin-bottom:0;}

#info ul {list-style:none;}

#info ul li a {text-decoration:none; color:#000;}

#col1{float:left; width:295px;font-size:16px;  color:#000; margin-right:0;}

#col2{float:left; margin-right:50px;}
```

Comment: Why are trying to achieve table layout with ULs?

Comment: And it's not margin right. It's its width. Here it is removed: http://jsfiddle.net/r2Y6d/6/

Comment: Thanks, it also worked! Is that the problem! And why you think tables its better for this situation? Because I read that tabless is the way!

Comment: Not always. When displaying tabular data tables are the best - this is what they're meant to do.

Comment: Hmm ok, thank you! But now I have this working fine and if it is only one aspect of more correct method, I think I'll mantain the ulists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/5A2xq/) what you are trying to do?
I removed the `width:295px;`, `margin-right:0;` and add `#col3{float:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your first column, `#col1`, **doesn't** have a right margin, because you set `margin-right:0;` to it.

Rather, your `ul`s have a left padding on them, which is set by default by the browser (left margin on IE 7, all other browsers are left padding.)

To remove the default, you need to add two properties to your rule:

```
#info ul {list-style:none; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2Y6d/5/

That will get rid of the left margin.

However, it does look like tabular data. If you don't know already, the most semantic HTML structure for tabular data is a `<table>`. Or, if it's simple data-value pairs, you could use a definition list (`<dl>`).

Comment: Thanks, it works! But whats the difference of use tables or ul? The result is the same...there is some advantage using tables?

Comment: It has to do with what's the correct element for the job. A `ul` is for a list of items in any particular order. A `table` is for tabular data. This may not have any impact for a sighted user, however the difference for someone using assistive technologies (like a screen reader) is more problematic.